# Static config object similar to pythons logging object

Tags: python-2.7

The logger object is as I understand a singleton, only one instance can ever exist. You get a reference by this:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('MyLogger')
```

I would like to do the same with a global config object, rather then have to pass my config as a parameter. What is the best approach to do this?